# Update a specific Session Variable

Tags: php, arrays, session, variables

I am using this code to output all the registered session variables -

```
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_SESSION);
 echo "</pre>";
 exit();
```

This is what I get

```
Array
 (
[language] => english
[navigation] => navigationHistory Object
    (
        [path] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [get] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [post] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (

                        [get] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [post] => Array
                            (

                                [number] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
                                [x] => 62

                            )
                )

            )

        )
 )
```

I would like to update the **number** variable in the [1] Array from XXXXXXXX... to 555555. I tried

```
$_SESSION['number'] = "55555555555555";
```

but that just ended up creating a new session variable called **number outside the array** with the 555.. value and not updating the right one. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$_SESSION['navigation']->path[1]['post']['number']=123;
```

Comment: I am sorry I commented on yours by mistake. Yours worked like a charm. Thanks a million. You're great.

Comment: I might have spoken too soon. While it does seem to work, what I end up getting is the entire [1] array is shifted to [2] and I get a new [1] with the variable number as 123...?

Comment: OK NVM I figured it out. I was just placing your code in the wrong place. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It's a nested array/object, so you have to traverse down to the array variable you want to set:

```
$_SESSION['navigation']->path[1]['post']['number'] = "55555555555555";
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes perfect sense but I get the following error. 

Cannot use object of type navigationHistory as array

I know this is outside the original question, sorry.

Comment: The `path` is an object attribute, not an array index

Comment: @Landon Thanks, yep, missed that.  Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I often get confused on this myself and it takes me a bit to figure these really long guys out.  A really easy way for you to figure this stuff out yourself is to do the following:  At the end of your code, you have a print_r:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Take a guess what the next level in the hierarchy is:

```
print_r($_SESSION['navigation'])
```

Run that, if you get an error, try something else.  If it works, you should see a print of that guy and you're getting "closer" to your value.  Once that looks good, tack on another attribute:

```
print_r($_SESSION['navigation']->path);
```

Does that work? Ok, continue.  And do this all the way until you get exactly what you want.